# How to translate dynamic form choices

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-i18n

I am using the same form and changing the choices.

All of the choices have a translation.

Do I need to specify something in the form?

## forms.py

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    selection = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

## views.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
choices = [(_(i.choice), i.choice) for i in question.choices.all()]
form.fields['selection'].choices = choices
```

## template

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.selection }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn"/>
</form>
```

I tried

```
{% trans form.selection %}
```

but got the error"

```
'BoundField' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: It may help if you edit your post to include the **full** traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(_(i.choice), i.choice)` is in the wrong order, you won't see a translation. It's the **second** item that gets displayed, so you want to have: `(i.choice, _(i.choice))`.

---

Also, if you want a dynamic form, you should be creating a dynamic form using a form factory.

Do not play with the form internals after you've created it.

Somewhere in your code:

```
def make_question_form_class(question):
     choices = [(_(i.choice), i.choice) for i in question.choices.all()]

     class _QuestionForm(forms.Form):
         selection = forms.ChoiceField(choices = choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

     return _QuestionForm
```

In your view:

```
form_class = make_question_form_class(question)
form = form_class(request.POST)
```

---

See [this post by James Bennett himself](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/) for more possibilities!

Comment: I am using you code. And it works. It just doesn't translate the choices.

Comment: @Siecje yes, see my edit (first line of the post). You're using the translation as the value not the display name. Then leave the template without `{% trans %}`.

Comment: @Siecje  Also, you might want to consider using `ugettext_lazy` instead of `ugettext` here (as mentioend in the other post), but this shouldn't change anything, it's just better practice.

Comment: It works, but it only translates the first two, not sure why but my question is definetly solved, thanks!

Comment: @Siecje probably missing translations for the others ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The translation needs to occur at template rendering time. For this, you either need the proper language to be set when running (how to achieve this depends on the exact context the code is running in):

```
choices = [(_(i.choice), i.choice) for i in question.choices.all()]
```

Or instead use `ugettext_lazy`, which will not translate the choices, but defer translation until rendering time:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
choices = [(_(i.choice), i.choice) for i in question.choices.all()]
```

In the template, always use:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.selection }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn"/>
</form>
```

The `form.selection` object is a `BoundField` object and cannot be translated directly.